# Using expand on a members of group query in Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, graphserviceclient

I am trying to build a query where I pass in a groupId parameter, and in return get all users and their group memberships, using the GraphServiceClient in C#.

I am able to get users and group memberships in one query, and I am able to get all users by groupId (but without group memberships) in a separate query. But I have not been able to merge these 2 queries into a single result. Is it possible?

Here is my code to get users and their group memberships (using expand with memberOf):

```cs
var users = await _graphServiceClient.Users
                .Request()
                .Filter(graphFilter) // used for searching on givenName and surname
                .Select($"givenName,surname,mail,mobilePhone,id,userPrincipalName")
                .Expand(e => e.MemberOf)
                .GetAsync();
```

And here is my code to get users in a given group:

```cs
var users = await _graphServiceClient
            .Groups[groupId] // Id of the group I want to get users from
            .Members
            .Request()
            .Select($"givenName,surname,mail,mobilePhone,id,userPrincipalName")
            //.Expand(e => e.MemberOf) // e is a DirectoryObject, so this does not compile.
            //.Expand(e => (e as Microsoft.Graph.User).MemberOf)
            //.Expand("memberOf")
            .GetAsync();
```

Is there any way to solve my case? I am currently looking into a new approach, whether MemberOf can be used in a filter while requesting from /users, but I am not sure yet whether it is possible either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing this within the Graph Explorer by using this query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/members/microsoft.graph.user?$expand=memberOf
```

Adding this *special parameter for the type* makes the usage a little complicated, but it can be done:

```
var url = serviceClient.Groups[groupId].Members.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.user?$expand=memberOf");
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
await serviceClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(request);
var response = await serviceClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(request);
```

#### Update for V5 SDK

In the current V5 SDK this call is directly supported by the following method:

```
var users = await serviceClient.Groups[groupToAdd].Members.GraphUser.GetAsync(config =>
    config.QueryParameters.Expand = new[] { "memberOf" });
```

Comment: Thank you, glad to see it is possible! I am gonna try some more to get it to work with the C# client. Worst case, I suppose I can just make my own client with custom URLs, but I hope I can use the client by Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks for the example! We have tried for a few days, but have not been able to find a better way than this, so we are using this code. Select-query can be added after the microsoft.graph.user-part as a parameter, but filtering seems not to be supported. As we do not have that many users (and filtering is an optional searc-parameter in our end), we are filtering on the results for now.

Comment: Probably you already tried it out, but just to be sure: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) mentions the possibility to filter on nested child properties like this example `$filter=param/any(var:var/subparam eq 'value-to-match')`, but if this really works highly depends on the exact target type and if the API supports it for the concrete type.